# HTTP Live Streaming - Byte-range in m3u8 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to get an m3u8 file with byteranges(#EXT-X-BYTERANGE), but with several segments (.TS).

the unique and functional solution is used:

> -hls_flags single_file

but I do not want only one file, but several with approximate 20MB

Does anyone have any ideas?

my main idea was to split the mp4 file into relative sizes, and use single_file -hls_flags, to create the m3u8 file with byteranges and then form a new m3u8 file with all parts...